# Adding a Java Interface to a WebView always behaves strangely on the emulator

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using a WebView to load an URL and then add a Java interface, because I inject a JavaScript `onPagefinish()` method.
This seems to work fine when I am using a physical device for debugging.

But on my emulator it doesn't work.
I have observed that this only happens on adding the Java interface or injecting some JavaScript.

This is what I get:

```
W/dalvikvm(580): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x406be3f0 points to non-array object    (Ljava/lang/String;)
I/dalvikvm(580): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
I/dalvikvm(580):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051ed98 self=0x29b408
I/dalvikvm(580):   | sysTid=588 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2733376
I/dalvikvm(580):   | schedstat=( 15943622613 6562821339 1142 )
I/dalvikvm(580):   at         android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(580):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(580):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadUrl(BrowserFrame.java:246)
I/dalvikvm(580):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.loadUrl(WebViewCore.java:1570)
I/dalvikvm(580):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$1400(WebViewCore.java:53)
I/dalvikvm(580):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:956)
I/dalvikvm(580):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
I/dalvikvm(580):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
I/dalvikvm(580):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
I/dalvikvm(580):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
E/dalvikvm(580): VM aborting
```

I found many questions about the same VM aborting error, but nothing helped me.  Is this a bug in the emulator, or a problem that has no solution at all?

Comment: Do you find any solution for this ? Because I am also having the same problem and not able to find out the solution.

Comment: What is your android version . It seems that in some emulator version, Java-Javascript bridge was not workin

Comment: No:(..i guess this is a bug in emulator

Comment: Yes as always... Emulator is buggy.

Comment: The emulator main purpose is to present an initial quick screen display, with expected inputs. The emulator on itself is VERY buggy, and lack most functionalities (such as Multi touch, Sensors, etc). Even Google sugest using an actual device (they suggest Nexus). In my experience, is worth noticing that manufactures will ..."harm"... the operational system. Sometimes just replacing a Class with one of their own, sometimes making the device "brick" if a root is attempted, or any unwanted operation is executed. I have even seen cases where a device would loop-shutdown based on date...